# Highslider issue

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I have used highslide gallery js in my web page. This slider displays only images. By clicking the thumbnail images, the enlarge image will display. But the client wants to display youtube video, vimeo video like this. Is there is any possible to display video in highslide. Or any other reference for video+image gallery? Please help. I spent more times to search. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can go through [MULTIMEDIA GALLERY FOR IMAGES, VIDEO AND AUDIO](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/24/multimedia-gallery/)

The structure of the XML file used by this plugin looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MultimediaGallery>
    <file type="photo">
        <thumb>media/photos/thumbs/3.jpg</thumb>
        <source>media/photos/3.jpg</source>
        <description>this is a description</description>
    </file>
    <file type="video">
        <thumb>media/videos/thumbs/html5.png</thumb>
        <source>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siOHh0uzcuY</source>
        <description>Youtube Video: Introduction to HTML5</description>
    </file>
    <file type="video">
        <thumb>media/videos/thumbs/bbbtrailer.png</thumb>
        <source>media/videos/video1.ogg</source>
        <source>media/videos/video1.m4v</source>
        <description>Video Integration Example: BBB Trailer</description>
    </file>
    <file type="audio">
        <thumb>media/audio/thumbs/audio1.jpg</thumb>
        <source>media/audio/audio1.ogg</source>
        <source>media/audio/audio1.mp3</source>
        <description>Audio Example</description>
    </file>
    ...
</MultimediaGallery>
```

another option is **http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox**

see [the examples](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example5/)

Comment: You are right. I found this slider already. But my design is differ from this slider.

Comment: see the another option in my answer

Comment: Thank you for ur comment. I check the demos and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Highslide Example of Playing Youtube Videos:

```
<div class="textwrapper">
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/znb6_J8npxM&hl=nb_NO&fs=1&" onclick="return openYouTube(this)" class="highslide">
        YouTube w/fade effect
    </a>
</div>
```

Extracted from: http://highslide.com/